# Como poderia melhorar o código?

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código

Existe alguma forma de melhorar esse código?

```
lista = [0,0,0,0,0]
acuNota = 0
x = 0
arq = open("notas","w")


while x <= 4:
    lista[x]= float(input("Insira uma nota por favor!"))    
    acuNota = acuNota + lista[x]
    print ("Criando arquivo em txt...")
    arq.write(str(lista[x])+ " - ") 
    x = x + 1   

print  ("A média das suas notas  é: %5.2f"% (acuNota/5.0) ) 

while True:
    op = 0
    op = int(input("Deseja ver a nota ? digite de 1 a 5 para ver e 0 para sair"))
    if (op==0) or (op >= 6):
        print ("Proibido ser maior ou igual a 6!")
        break
    print ("Nota: %5.2f " % lista[op-1] )
```

Comment: Valeu pessoal pelas dicas, não usei o for ainda por que ainda não chegou na parte ainda do livro do python.

Comment: Está questão está sendo discutida no aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4217/3635

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Ia só comentar mas ficou grande.

Essencialmente não, afinal ele faz muito pouca coisa.

A não ser que você queira aplicar uma série de coisas que se costuma recomendar em termos de arquitetura, mas seria um absurdo fazer isto em um exemplo tão simples. Tudo é contexto, e neste contexto fazer o melhor não é o mais importante. Eu só recomendaria não cometer erros absurdos, não fazer de qualquer jeito. Neste contexto de um código de aprendizado é mais importante cuidar da legibilidade, do estilo de codificação, de estar correto, do que da boa arquitetura, performance, etc.

Claro que tem pequenos detalhes que podem ser mudados, mas provavelmente mais por gosto do que por necessidade. Então eu:

- padronizaria os espaçamento entre operadores
- eventualmente daria nomes melhores para as variáveis
- cuidaria para **garantir** o fechamento do arquivo mesmo se der erro, que sequer está sendo feito em condições normais
- faria uma verificação da entrada de dados
- mudaria pelo menos a escrita na tela de criação do arquivo para o local onde efetivamente cria o arquivo
- não atribuiria valores para a mesma variável sem necessidade (`op = 0`)
- declararia as variáveis mais próximas de onde são usadas
- talvez usaria um `op > 5` no lugar de `op >= 6`
- mudaria o `op==0` para `op <= 0` e mudaria a mensagem para `"Os valores devem ser entre 1 e 5."`

Tem outras perfumarias que podem ser feitas, mas isto é o mais importante para um caso assim.

Percebeu como ainda está pecando no básico? Não tente fazer perfeito antes de acertar o fundamento.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz o seguinte:

```
lista = [0,0,0,0,0]
acuNota = 0
arq = open("notas","w")


for x in range(5):
    lista[x]= float(input("Insira uma nota por favor: "))    
    acuNota += lista[x]
    print ("Criando arquivo em txt...")
    arq.write(str(lista[x])+ " - ")   

print  ("A média das suas notas  é: %5.2f"% (acuNota/5.0) ) 

while True:
    op = int(input("Deseja ver a nota ? digite de 1 a 5 para ver e 0 para sair: "))
    if (op <= 0) or (op >= 6):
        print ("Proibido ser maior ou igual a 6!")
        break
    print ("Nota: %5.2f " % lista[op-1] )
```

A primeira coisa que eu fiz, foi substituir o seu `while loop` por um `for loop`, pois eles são mais rápidos. Isso eliminou também a necessidade da sua variável contadora `x`. Troquei o `acuNota = acuNota + lista[x]` por um `acuNota += lista[x]`, que é basicamente a mesma coisa, só um detalhe.

Também era desnecessário iniciar a variável `op` com um valor de `0`. O usuário vai ser obrigado a colocar um valor, de qualquer forma, então eliminei essa variável.

Por último, fiz uma modificação nas restrições que você deu para o dado que o usuário inseriu. Considerei também a possibilidade do usuário colocar um valor menor que zero, mudando de `if op == 0` para `if op <= 0`. Se você souber lidar com exceções, o programa vai ficar melhor também.

Answer (score 3):

Eu deixaria o código mais legível e faria algumas modificações:

```
lista = [0,0,0,0,0]
nota_acumulada = 0
arquivo = open("notas","w")

for x in range(5):
    lista[x]= float(input("Insira uma nota por favor: "))    
    nota_acumulada += lista[x]

# guarda as notas no arquivo
arquivo.write(' - '.join(map(str, lista))  

print ("A média das suas notas  é: %5.2f"% (nota_acumulada/5.0) ) 

while True:
    escolha = int(input("Deseja ver a nota ? digite de 1 a 5 para ver e 0 para sair: "))
    if 0 < escolha < 6:
        print ("Nota: %5.2f " % lista[escolha-1] )
    else:
        break
```

É claro que seu código faltaria colocar exceções, pois se o usuário digitar um outro caractere que não seja número irá ocorrer erro.